# Using REST API to create alerting rule in Kibana fails on 400 "Invalid action groups: default"

Tags: rest, kibana, monitoring, elastic-stack, elk

I have ELK cloud v. 7.13.2 and trying to create alert rule with slack action via REST API. This is my curl invocation:

`curl -u ****** -s -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://***********.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/api/alerting/rule -X POST -d @src/rules/cpu_utilization.json`

I am expecting that new rule is created, but unfortunately I am getting following error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Invalid action groups: default"
}
```

The contents of src/rules/cpu_utilization.json are:

```
{
  "params": {
    "nodeType": "host",
    "criteria": [
      {
        "comparator": ">",
        "timeSize": 1,
        "metric": "cpu",
        "threshold": [
          80
        ],
        "timeUnit": "m"
      }
    ],
    "sourceId": "default"
  },
  "consumer": "alerts",
  "schedule": {
    "interval": "1m"
  },
  "tags": [],
  "name": "CPU2",
  "throttle": "1000d",
  "enabled": true,
  "rule_type_id": "metrics.alert.inventory.threshold",
  "notify_when": "onThrottleInterval",
  "actions": [
    {
      "group": "default",
      "id": "fce4c27f-d22a-4209-858c-253a06511c1b",
      "params": {
        "message": "{{alertName}} - {{context.group}} is in a state of {{context.alertState}}\n\nReason:\n{{context.reason}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Documentation says clearly:

```
Properties of the action objects:
group
(Required, string) Grouping actions is recommended for escalations for different types of alerts. If you don’t need this, set this value to default.
```

Is this a bug in ELK or I am doing something wrong? I am able to use API for other purposes, like listing rules, deleting rules etc. I am also capable of creating a rule without an action, but this doen`t seem to be too useful...

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, I got an answer from ELK support. Apparently, you can use another endpoint to list all rule types `GET /api/alerting/rule_types`. Then you need to find your type and lookup property `default_action_group_id` - it will hold the correct value. Eg. in the above example it was:

```
"default_action_group_id": "metrics.inventory_threshold.fired"
```